# Spyder IDE : How do i remote into a kernel. e.g. from my pc to a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, python, ide

How do I remotely connect to a python kernel using spyder IDE.  I've search online for instructions but i find any that help.

Comment: How do you even know this is possible? Surely there's documentation on it somewhere if you think it is... I've never heard of Spyder IDE personally, so without something to go on, there isn't much many of us can do to help.

Answer (score 3):

The steps below are confirmed to work using Spyder 3.1.4 IDE on a Debian Jessie or Ubuntu Xenial, to connect on a Raspberry Pi 2, using Raspbian Jessie, to run Python 2.7 scripts - however, I think they can work in any similar situation.

Prerequisites:

1. You must be able to connect to the server(Pi) using ssh *without a password*
   (e.g. use `ssh-copy-id` or similar to copy your local key to the server).
2. Spyder installed on your client.
3. The ability of the client to mount a Pi's path (optional, but it will save you lots of effort) - if your client is *Nix, then `sshfs`, if it's windows then any similar program
4. `iPython` installed on the server (Pi)
   I am not sure if the whole thing can work without iPython but, anyway, it's a nice thing to have: It's *way* better than the normal Python console...

STEPS:

1. Using any means at hand (ssh, vnc, Teamviewer, physical access) start an iPython console on the server (Pi), using `ipython` or Pi's GUI.
   This will output something like:

   ```
   Python 2.7.9 (default, Sep 17 2017, 20:26:04)  
   Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
   IPython 2.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.  
   ?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.  
   %quickref -> Quick reference.  
   help      -> Python's own help system.  
   object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.  
   %guiref   -> A brief reference about the graphical user interface.
   ```
2. Issue a `%connect_info` command (this is known as "connect_info magic")
   This will output something like:

   ```
   In [1]: %connect_info  
   {  
     "stdin_port": 56159,  
     "ip": "127.0.0.1",  
     "control_port": 59261,  
     "hb_port": 36977,  
     "signature_scheme": "hmac-sha256",  
     "key": "8c5d0c44-0eb1-5699-1db7-f0d175bde37f",  
     "shell_port": 55033,  
     "transport": "tcp",  
     "iopub_port": 54787 
   }  
   Paste the above JSON into a file, and connect with:  
       $> ipython <app> --existing <file>  
   or, if you are local, you can connect with just:  
       $> ipython <app> --existing kernel-14046.json  
   or even just:  
       $> ipython <app> --existing  
   if this is the most recent IPython session you have started.
   ```
3. (Informative) This information is put in a json file (in Raspberry):

   ```
   $ sudo find / -name "kernel*.json"  
   /home/pi/.ipython/profile_default/security/kernel-23143.json
   ```

   And the contents of this file:

   ```
   $ cat /home/pi/.ipython/profile_default/security/kernel-23143.json  
   {  
   "stdin_port": 57511,  
   "ip": "127.0.0.1",  
   "control_port": 52447,  
   "hb_port": 50009,  
   "signature_scheme": "hmac-sha256",  
   "key": "8c5d0c44-0eb1-5699-1db7-f0d175bde37f",  
   "shell_port": 54319,  
   "transport": "tcp",  
   "iopub_port": 46791  
   }
   ```
4. As it is stated in the instructions in the iPython console, you can paste the above info in a local json file and use this (see next step), so the existence of the server's json file is of little importance. By experience, however, it saves a lot of effort if this file and, more important, the (path to the) Python code you'll be creating on the server is mounted locally.
   In the *client* side:

   ```
   $ sudo mkdir /home/pi
   ```

   **this will contain the entire home dir of the server's user (pi) - a little extra care is due**...

   ```
   $ sudo chown my_local_user:my_localgroup /home/pi
   ```

   **this allows the local user to have *complete* access to the server's (Pi's) home dir - YOU MUST BE CAREFUL what you do with it!**
   Finally, mount pi's home:

   ```
   $ sshfs pi@server_IP:/home/pi /home/pi -o idmap=user -o compression=yes -o reconnect -o follow_symlinks
   ```
5. From Spyder's "Consoles" menu, choose "Connect to an existing kernel"
6. Use the browse button to the right of "Path to connection file or kernel id" and navigate to the locally mounted json file (since we have mounted pi's home in our /home/pi in step 3, the paths are identical, no matter if you call the json from the server or the local box - in my case: /home/pi/.ipython/profile_default/security/kernel-23143.json)
7. Check "This is a remote kernel" checkbox - this will enable the following three fields
8. In the "Host name" field input the ssh connection you use to connect to the server - eg pi@server_IP. You'll need to append :server_port only if the server listens to a non-default port.
9. For the "Path to the ssh key file", browse to your local ssh key - mine is the /home/local_username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (You may need to 'show hidden files' and select files of all types `*.*` - spyder is by default looking for .pem files)
10. If you have set a passphrase for your key, enter it in the last field "Password..." - otherwise just leave it blank.
11. When you hit OK, it will take a few seconds and a new iPython console will open inside spyder which, instead of being labeled something like Console 1/A, it will show server_user@server_IP.

I use the above solution very often, to connect my Ubuntu box with tons of resources and a big monitor to my Pi. For the time being I have no security concerns in this environment. However, mounting the entire pi's home locally *screams* for caution - perhaps it would be wiser to mount only the necessary subdirs.

That's it - enjoy!

PS:
While the above solution uses local resources to run Spyder, there is another approach to the task: Install Spyder on the Pi, issue an `ssh -Y pi@the_pi_ip` locally and type `spyder` - this will open Spyder's GUI *locally*, but Spyder itself will be running *on the Pi* (there will be big performance degradation).

Comment: Brilliant. I'll take a look tomorrow :-)

Comment: When i connect from the client(windows 7) to the pi( server) I receive the error "could not open ssh tunnel. The error was: Paramiko not available"

8. I beleive its standard? When I connect through putty, its the standard port - 
9. Entered pi@192.168.1.2 (i dont have SSH Key file) just the password for the pi user. - 
10. tried ssh password for the username pi and leaving it blank. - 
11. i receive the error "could not open ssh tunnel. The error was: Paramiko not available"

Comment: 8: It is.   9: You MUST setup password-less SSH - see prerequisite #1 - there is no way around it, as far as I know.  11: If memory serves, Paramiko is something you can pip-install.  I'd google something like "Paramiko pip windows 7".  If you don't find anything, let me know and I'll check my docs.

Comment: ah i missed that one.  I'll get on and test it :-)

Comment: Just to be sure, Paramiko would need to be installed on the client side only, not the server (Raspberry Pi)?

Comment: Well, common logic suggests the client side - i'd give it 99.9%.

Comment: Have you managed it yet?

Comment: Hey, sorry I haven't yet.  i dont want to open ssh without passwords on the pi its intended for.  However, i intend to test it on a alternative, just havent got around to it yet.

Comment: Passwordless SSH works *only* for the client-server pair you set it for - it is a safe and common practice, you can look it up.  Besides, when you ask Spyder (or any other program) to run some code elsewhere, it has no other way of performing its task - think about it...

Comment: On a side-note, you still have the option I mentioned in my initial PS - although I'd consider it a waste if your only fear is SSH.

Comment: Hey, it's been a while...  If you need more help, let me know.  If all is OK, marking the answer as accepted would be appreciated - trying to build some reputation here... ;)